# Custom Settings allow limit is 0MB in Sandbox

Tags: apex, sandbox, customsetting, developer-console

I try to update Custom Settings in my sandbox org. And I meet CUSTOM_SETTINGS_LIMIT_EXCEEDED error message.

I found Custom Settings in my Sandbox allow limit is 0MB. Please see follow picture.

[image]

How can I change the allow limit?

Best wishes,
Lee

Comment: Potentially your Data Storage limit has exceeded in general. Go to > Setup > Administration Setup > Company Profile > Company Information and review Used Data Space.

Comment: You can try 1. Match production and sandbox licenses(https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000335272&type=1&mode=1) 2. Sandbox refresh.

Comment: @TSmith, My sandbox used data space 98%, is this the reason cause this issue?